# APP_INITIALIZER is not firing before factory

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I'm using `APP_INITIALIZER` to load environment specific variables. I need to use these variables inside of my `authConfigFactory`, but the factory keeps loading before `APP_INITIALIZER` has completed inside of the app config.

I'm using this library: https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc

I want to use the value of `APP_CONFIG.authConfig.allowedUrls` inside of my auth config factory. How can I make sure it sets the configuration first before the auth factory.

I get this error in the factory : `Cannot read property 'authConfig' of undefined`

`app.module.ts`:

```
providers: [
    AppConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (config: AppConfigService) => () => config.load(),
      multi: true,
      deps: [AppConfigService]
    },
    {
      provide: OAuthModuleConfig,
      useFactory: authConfigFactory
    }
]
```

`app.config.ts`:

```
export let APP_CONFIG: AppConfig;

@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService {
  constructor(
    private injector: Injector
  ) {}

  config = null;

  public load() {
    const http = this.injector.get(HttpClient);

    return http
      .get('../assets/config/config.json')
      .pipe(
        tap(returnedConfig => {
          const t = new AppConfig();
          APP_CONFIG = Object.assign(t, returnedConfig);
        })
      )
      .toPromise();
  }

}
```

`auth-config-factor`:

```
export function authConfigFactory(): OAuthModuleConfig {
  return {
    resourceServer: {
      allowedUrls: APP_CONFIG.authConfig.allowedUrls,
      sendAccessToken: true
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: The value for `APP_CONFIG` is asynchronously being set, so you will need the value to be some sort of asynchronous result type (i.e. observable/subject/promise) so that your code that needs it can wait until it has finished loading.

Comment: How would I implement that? Here is a stack overflow answer that helped me get started with using `APP_INITIALIZER`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49559009/angular5-deploying-angular-application-to-multiple-clients/49559443. 

I didn't see anywhere they used an observable for `APP_CONFIG`.

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem before and tried many possibilities with no luck, the only solution is that i used ngrx/store

In app.config.ts you can dispatch an action to save the config in the store, and you can get it after that in other services by doing: store.select()   Subscribe to  it and do your control

**app.module.ts**

```
providers: [
 AuthService, // oidc-client.ts where i need the config from json
 DataService,
 ConfigService,
 {
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: loadConfig,
  deps: [ConfigService],
  multi: true,
 },
```

**config.service.ts**

```
  import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
  import { IAppStore } from '../models/store.model';
  import * as ConfigActions from '../store/actions/config.actions';

  @Injectable()
   export class ConfigService {
   public config: any = {};

   constructor(private http: HttpClient, private store: Store<IAppStore>) {}

   getConfig(key: string): string {
     return this.config[key] || '';
    }
  public loadConfig() {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get('app-config.json').subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.config = response;
        this.store.dispatch(new ConfigActions.AddConfig(response)); // dispatch action to update the store
        resolve(true);
      }
    );
  });
  }}
```

**AuthService**

```
  import { Log, User, UserManager, WebStorageStateStore } from 'oidc-client';
  ...
  @Injectable()
  export class AuthService {
  private _userManager: UserManager;
  public _user: User;
  constructor(
    private store: Store<IAppStore>
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private route: Router,
    private configs: ConfigService
  ) {
this.store.select('appConfig').subscribe((configdata) => {
  Log.logger = console;
  const config = {
  authority: configdata.stsAuthority,
  client_id: configdata.clientId,
  redirect_uri: `${configdata.clientRoot}/#/auth-callback#`,
  scope: 'openid profile fusionApi.full_access',
  response_type: 'id_token token',
  post_logout_redirect_uri: `${configdata.clientRoot}?postLogout=true`, // delet all stored tokens after logout
  userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage }),
  automaticSilentRenew: true,
  silent_redirect_uri: `${configdata.clientRoot}/assets/html/silent-refresh-redirect.html`,
};
  this._userManager = new UserManager(config);
  this._userManager.getUser().then((user) => {
  if (user && !user.expired) {
    this._user = user;
  }
});
 ...
}

login(): Promise<any> {
 return this._userManager.signinRedirect();
}
...
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for sharing. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: What does `IAppStore` and `ConfigActions` look like? I'm not super familiar with ngrx, although I'm going through some tutorials now.

Comment: IappStore is an interface that contain  contain all state properties and configActions are the list of actions (add config and delete config) in that case

Comment: here is a great tutorial https://coursetro.com/posts/code/151/Angular-Ngrx-Store-Tutorial---Learn-Angular-State-Management

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem and fix it.

module-factory:

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpBackend } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthorizationService } from './authorization.service';

export const AUTH_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<string>('auth.config.path', {
    factory: () => 'config.json',
  });


  export function CheckAuthorizationState(handler: HttpBackend, authService: AuthorizationService, path: string) {
    return async () => {
      const http = new HttpClient(handler);
      // get config for authorization
      await http.get(path)
        .pipe(
          map((response: any) => {
            authService.init(response);
          })
        ).toPromise();
      // check authorization
      await authService.checkAuthorization();
    };
  }
```

module:

```
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER, ModuleWithProviders, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AuthorizationService } from './authorization.service';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthorizationGuardService } from './authorization-guard.service';
import { AuthorizationInterceptor } from './authorization-interpretator';
import { HttpBackend, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { CheckAuthorizationState, AUTH_CONFIG } from './module-factories';




@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthorizationService,
    AuthorizationGuardService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: CheckAuthorizationState,
      deps: [HttpBackend, AuthorizationService, AUTH_CONFIG],
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthorizationInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  declarations: []
})

export class AuthorizationModule {
  static forRoot(path: string): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: AuthorizationModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: AUTH_CONFIG, useValue: path }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Here is my authorization library which publish for you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sso-authorization-oidc-client

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue just today and the following is how I managed to fix it. hoping this might be helpful to someone.

This is specific to `angular-oauth2-oidc` in a way

```js
export const oauthModuleConfigFactory = (config: AppConfig): OAuthModuleConfig => ({
    resourceServer: {
        allowedUrls: [config.apiUrl],
        sendAccessToken: true
    }
});

// OAuthModuleConfig is provided by OAuthModule as useValue
// and Angular resolves useValue providers before APP_INITIALIZER
// This may be a bug, since Angular still attempts to resolve the value
// even if it has been overriden with a useFactory as below
const fixForAppInitializers = ({ ngModule, providers = [] }: ModuleWithProviders<any>) => ({
    ngModule,
    providers: [...providers.filter((value: any) => value.provide !== OAuthModuleConfig)]
});

@NgModule({
    imports: [fixForAppInitializers(OAuthModule.forRoot())],
    providers: [
        AuthGuard,
        { provide: OAuthModuleConfig, useFactory: oauthModuleConfigFactory, deps: [APP_CONFIG] },
        ...
    ]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

That wasn't enough though, because `OAuthModule`'s `DefaultOAuthInterceptor` requires `OAuthModuleConfig` which needs the `app.config.json` to load first, but in order to load the config we need to use the `HttpClient` which injects `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` on request, thus throwing `config is not loaded` error below.

This is how I solved that problem:

```js
// We're using the primitive HttpXhrBackend service instead of HttpClient
// so that it does not attempt to inject http interceptors
// which has app config as a dependency, thus attempting to inject the config
// before it's loaded and throwing an error in the process
@Injectable()
export class AppConfigLoader {

    private _config: AppConfig | undefined;

    public constructor(
        private readonly httpClient: HttpXhrBackend
    ) { }

    public get config(): AppConfig {
        if (!this._config) {
            throw new Error('config is not loaded');
        }
        return this._config;
    }

    public async load(): Promise<void> {
        const request = this.createJsonRequest<AppConfig>(`${window.location.origin}/app.config.json`);
        this._config = await this.httpClient.handle(request).pipe(
            filter(event => event instanceof HttpResponse),
            map((response: any) => response.body)
        ).toPromise();
    }

    private createJsonRequest<T>(url: string): HttpRequest<T> {
        return new HttpRequest<T>('GET', url, { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'content-type': 'application/json' }) });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The OAuthModuleConfig needs to be set synchronously. So the settings need to be loaded before the OAuthModuleConfig is created (in a factory).

I implemented it by loading the settings before the AppModule is bootstrapped.

Main.ts:

```
fetch('/assets/config.json')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(config => {

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic([{ provide: APP_SETTINGS, useValue: config }])
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

App.module.ts

Inside the module declaration:

```
....
providers: [
{ provide: OAuthModuleConfig, useFactory: authConfigFactory, deps: [APP_SETTINGS] },
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
.....


export function authConfigFactory(settings: AppSettings): OAuthModuleConfig {
return {
resourceServer: {
    allowedUrls: settings.protectedUrls,
    sendAccessToken: true,
   }
 };
}
```

Comment: what is the config.json ?

Comment: Can be any json file containing some settings you need for configuring your application

Checkout https://github.com/dtiemstra/AngularConfigDemo for an example